# SQLAlchemy, Postgres, getting distinct to join with Alchemy model

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, distinct

I'm relatively new to SQLAlchemy, and thus far have not had to do anything that complex. I now have a need to return the latest "version" of a row. I can use "distinct" to return the relevant list, however I'm struggling to have the query return SQLAlchemy models.

```
 session.query(Document.document_id,func.max(Document.id)).\
    filter_by(container_id=1,active=True).\
    group_by(Document.document_id).all()
```

This returns the list of ids that I need. But what I really need is the whole model.

I'm sure there's a simple way to join it. However it has completely eluded me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [subquery](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.subquery), you can than join:

```
subq = (session.query(
            # Document.document_id, # do not need this really
            func.max(Document.id).label("max_id")
        )
        .filter(Document.container_id == 1)
        .filter(Document.active == True)
        .group_by(Document.document_id)
        ).subquery("subq")

qry = (session.query(Document)
        .join(subq, Document.id == subq.c.max_id)
        ).all()
```